# I don't understand for loops and nested loop

Tags: python, loops

A python beginner here
I have been following Programming With Mosh's tutorial on Python and I have been stuck on for loops and nested loops. I have gone through tons of YouTube tutorials on for loops and nested loops but I just dont get it.

```
for x in items:
         for y in items
```

are we creating x as a new variable or what? And what value does x have and how can we mess with it in the loop? Please explain in a simple way.

Comment: Please provide at least some code with correct indentation and correct syntax (colon). Which video did you watch and what exact problem do you have? This site does not provide tutorials, so we're not gonna write another one for you.

Comment: Yes, `x` is a new variable. On each iteration through the loop it has the next item from `items`. You can use it as you would any other variable. Perhaps you should look for tutorials outside of YouTube if none of them have helped.

Comment: `x` will have the value of whatever is picked from the list called `items`. It will have the first item in the first iteration of the loop, the second item in the second iteration of the loop, etc. You can do with x whatever you like, just like any variable.

Comment: Typically it does not make sense to have a nested loop over the *same* list as before. So the `y` loop in your example does not cover a typical nested loop scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a list of fruits:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

This loop loops through the items in the list:

```
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
```

And gives this output:

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

So here's what's actually happening inside the loop.

First, the compiler creates a new variable called `x` (it can be called anything you want it to be but here it's called `x`).

Then the compiler looks at the first value in the list `fruits` (or whichever list you're looping through) which in this case is `apple`, and assigns it to `x`.

```
for x in fruits:
```

That means that when you run

```
print(x) # really means print("apple")
```

since x holds the value `apple`, `apple` will be outputted.

Now the compiler reaches the end of the loop, so it starts again with the next element.

```
print(x) # really means print("banana")
```

`x` is assigned the next value in the list, which is `banana`, so this time it outputs `banana`, and so on and so forth.

You can do whatever you like with the variable `x` inside the loop, the same way that you could do whatever you like with a variable that you create yourself, for example `my_fruit = "grapefruit"`.

For example:

```
my_fruit = "grapefruit"
print(my_fruit)
my_fruit.replace("a", "x")

# output:
# grapefruit
# grxpefruit
```

is the same thing as:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
    x.replace("a", "x")

# output:
# apple
# xpple
# banana
# bxnxnx
# cherry
# cherry
```

Hope that clarifies loops for you! I remember being very confused about the `x` variable (or its equivalent) when I was learning loops...

Answer (score 0):

Loops can be nested in Python, as they can with other programming languages.

A nested loop is a loop that occurs within another loop, structurally similar to nested if statements. These are constructed like so:

```
for [first iterating variable] in [outer loop]: # Outer loop
    [do something]  # Optional
    for [second iterating variable] in [nested loop]:   # Nested loop
        [do something]
```

The program first encounters the outer loop, executing its first iteration. This first iteration triggers the inner, nested loop, which then runs to completion.

Then the program returns back to the outer loop, completing the second iteration and again triggering the nested loop. Again, the nested loop runs to completion, and the program returns back to the outer loop until the sequence is complete or a break or other statement disrupts the process.

**Example:**

In this example, the outer loop will iterate through a list of integers called num_list, and the inner loop will iterate through a list of strings called alpha_list.

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for number in num_list:
    print(number)
    for letter in alpha_list:
        print(letter)
```

output:

```
1
a
b
c
2
a
b
c
3
a
b
c
```

The output illustrates that the program completes the first iteration of the outer loop by printing `1`, which then triggers completion of the inner loop, printing `a, b, c` consecutively and the same process is followed for each item of `num_list`.

Comment: "The code you have given must be wrong because iterating over same sequence in a nested loop does not make sense." - The op could be making columns like excel - "AA", "AB" etc

Comment: @Sayse yes that is possible!!...I did not consider that! thank you for pointing out!